# SPF softfail on gmail

Tags: postfix, smtp, spf, dkim, dmarc

I'm trying to setup my own smtp server with postfix and opendkim. I have publsished spf/dmarc/dkim recors, set up ptr. But currently, all my mail with any text goes into gmail spam folder. I have looked up email source, and found log like this ( i send from root@code-gmail.com on my account pav.testacc1234@gmail.com):

```
Delivered-To: pav.testacc1234@gmail.com
Received: by 10.138.18.148 with SMTP id p20csp4871365ocs;
        Tue, 1 May 2018 07:36:31 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AB8JxZrPQsmv/N1Awo0qfgsz0gw+wDo0r/51iNZttxRBUbhiu0Nb17eK3sNZcm4KP6Wu3B4aFxHJ
X-Received: by 2002:adf:c4c4:: with SMTP id o4-v6mr11895652wrf.173.1525185391907;
        Tue, 01 May 2018 07:36:31 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1525185391; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=MoZChW3AD7idVCBW5FJXjJw8V2Z5SL9g5H+/AT5GFoEExBs41FrFhG0xyOUt26G7xE
         JZS7fv8hrzZoJ5GUzX1Zr7SyD90ULVqrZxP2r1or/CYSLVrPplyyPe+B7p/GdR8AFW+I
         sXpROZ9yNOQ/bdbdmhTGpMUoMtxTGtyXssM0x2uICRGok8B3Q2RK5/FGN/izPdv2Dp2q
         wdy0JcD+db1xxfJtPo+uXtYldbsc079oGEyAnu4LEkz3SQ6OB34HOCfPbeEBB3gCT/dn
         igIM9YKAPqHL01yMYmCE153w8FkcrqE98SfBgEYKkQvBr2hy3aWOEJI01/+emGXPW9N+
         pc1Q==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=from:date:message-id:to:subject:dkim-signature
         :arc-authentication-results;
        bh=QY3eSg1xUkClxZc7O05HDfwJPvSkbBuZINP6T4PQvjc=;
        b=hzxAY6fLNrTitTipY+VheNRTRbBYwOy5JKW9LgDZxpnVWBnx9al3ZmUKaJTZbs3rk7
         GsArGQCHKityZSGjUg/YX9Vfv4gb4xurY4V1yP8MlYLQpFofmlbWiMX/W8FMmVOD2+aq
         8Kh0UzWYYGO1NtEV33h8FvzDeavrOu07Ol8g8Eq6oDUkjuZZHxEKSL9VeTvJUrz57qGn
         twwsNTKNHR1fnTMdNHMQcmGMKD37MF9no9X0whHVUhnPRedGeV8Z9YxNN6LCCRUEmw2y
         xhUZIbve9e3CX8g0X+pTJhHMouphTDByG1k8y+/JUeXrn2jD402QKuyy58GBPA4hC84z
         vE2w==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@code-gmail.com header.s=mail header.b=ccV1Vw1O;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning root@code-gmail.com does not designate 2a07:5741:0:eb4::1 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@code-gmail.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=code-gmail.com
Return-Path: <root@code-gmail.com>
Received: from code-gmail.com ([2a07:5741:0:eb4::1])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id 90-v6si8205147wre.4.2018.05.01.07.36.31
        for <pav.testacc1234@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 bits=256/256);
        Tue, 01 May 2018 07:36:31 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning root@code-gmail.com does not designate 2a07:5741:0:eb4::1 as permitted sender) client-ip=2a07:5741:0:eb4::1;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@code-gmail.com header.s=mail header.b=ccV1Vw1O;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning root@code-gmail.com does not designate 2a07:5741:0:eb4::1 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@code-gmail.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=code-gmail.com
Received: by code-gmail.com (Postfix, from userid 0) id C972B100E8B; Tue,
  1 May 2018 10:36:30 -0400 (EDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=code-gmail.com; s=mail; t=1525185390; bh=QY3eSg1xUkClxZc7O05HDfwJPvSkbBuZINP6T4PQvjc=; h=Subject:To:Date:From:From; b=ccV1Vw1OibcUg5jV3HZnGQd4mQfOLLaRDsnPwlMAukzQA9OQHpqzGjrkABXcHdAV6
     54Lz3BlbSoyBr9bFAaBI0BO9itAXBEWeh32zZBvpXkvd0ViNcSxOH7kWwtq6dUK7hB
     210wgjTKkmOBUmEg+Stu49tIfrO2gT4Xoyv7DyC0DxzHZagJ0yG/6UrsfwNeMiyBJc
     fLudtklc+omAPbkRUEM/EzuKQQPHEmvsDdWwGJtHAKfJ8rJtYh8ta0eAIHUm2II023
     dkFQhnFtZ8cew8aeTPmqBU+YmG9K94OYwZchCds1zwXt88djHkJZH/Z4qsyG8xCr0z
     OZyndTCWD042w==
Subject: Are you going to deliver thos trucks? We need to build stuff as soon as possible
To: <pav.testacc1234@gmail.com>
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 3.1.1)
Message-Id: <20180501143630.C972B100E8B@code-gmail.com>
Date: Tue,
  1 May 2018 10:36:30 -0400 (EDT)
From: root <root@code-gmail.com>

This is just an example text 2
```

As you can see i have this error:

`(google.com: domain of transitioning root@code-gmail.com does not designate 2a07:5741:0:eb4::1 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@code-gmail.com;`

But i have this ipv6 in my spf record, here how it looks like:

```
"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:94.156.35.221 ip6:2a07:5741:0:eb4:0:0:0:1 ip6:2a07:5741:0:eb4::1 ~all"
```

For some reason still softfail, and i think it's the main reason why the mail ends up in spam.

Comment: It looks good now, but maybe gmail read an earlier version of the SPF record and is caching it. What was the TTL before? With the TTL now it should be cleared within 2 hours.

Comment: @user188737 the TTL is set to 7200

Comment: If it was not set to a higher value early on, then it should be good within 2 hours. But of course that is a reasonable expectation given the TTL, not a certainty.

Comment: @user188737 yeah, the spf test pass now. But the email still arrive in the spam folder, but i guees it's another question now